# How to add Bootstrap 4 validation design into select2

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

We need to design the select2 enabled fields according to the [Bootstrap 4 default javascript validation API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#validation). We tried to assign necessary classes to the select2 `containerCssClass` like below:

```
let forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        $('.form-control.select2:invalid').select2({
            containerCssClass: 'form-control is-invalid border-danger'
        });
        $('.form-control.select2:valid').select2({
            containerCssClass: 'form-control is-valid border-success'
        });
    }, false);
});
```

But it's always is showing the invalid styling even the field is filled with valid data. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS you can resolve the issue very easily. Here you can have the SCSS/LESS code for that:

```css
.was-validated {
    .form-control.select2 + .select2-container .select2-selection,
    .custom-select.select2 + .select2-container .select2-selection {
        padding-right: calc(1.6em + 0.75rem);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center right calc(0.4em + 0.1875rem);
        background-size: calc(0.8em + 0.375rem) calc(0.8em + 0.375rem);
    }

    .form-control.select2:invalid + .select2-container .select2-selection,
    .custom-select.select2:invalid + .select2-container .select2-selection {
        border-color: #e3342f;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23e3342f' viewBox='-2 -2 7 7'%3e%3cpath stroke='%23e3342f' d='M0 0l3 3m0-3L0 3'/%3e%3ccircle r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cx='3' r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cy='3' r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cx='3' cy='3' r='.5'/%3e%3c/svg%3E");
    }

    .form-control.select2:valid + .select2-container .select2-selection,
    .custom-select.select2:valid + .select2-container .select2-selection {
        border-color: #38c172;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2338c172' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    }
}
```

The default validation API as mentioned in Bootstrap 4.3.1 adds a class when the form is submitted (`.was-validated`) and with this they have done some styling for the `:valid` and `:invalid` states. We simply copied those styling and DOM traversed to apply them to the Select2 containers.

In this way the styling will change when the form field state changes.